# The fastest way to filter 3D Array into one 1D Array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-xarray

I'm trying to filter several 3D Arrays by condition and use the results as the input for `scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d()` or `np.histogram2d()`.

Here's a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

array = xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(20, 2000, 3000))

stacked = array.stack(z=('dim_0', 'dim_1', 'dim_2'))
res = stacked.where(stacked>0, drop=True)
```

The `stack` steps work quite slow:

```
16.9 s ± 1 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Is it possible to get the `res` quicker and save the value of `dim_0`, `dim_1`, and `dim_2` as 1D variables too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you using xarray for here exactly?

Since both scipy and numpy will work on bare numpy arrays, you can simply take the data as a numpy array, and use `ravel` to get a 1D view of the same memory.

Please refer to the numpy manual if you're not yet familiar with copies and views: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.ndarray.html?highlight=view

This is lightning fast:

```py
ravelled = array.data.ravel()
```

As long as it's a 1D array, and you just need boolean indexing, numpy is fine:

```py
result = ravelled[ravelled > 0]
```

Comment: I'm reading netcdf files and want to also get the dim value for each valid data. Is it possible to save dims as 1D array too?

Comment: I find pandas works much faster than xarray ... Maybe just `to_dataframe()` solves this problem.